# Named parameter [XXX] is not registered with this procedure call

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am calling a procedure from Spring Boot. 
Getting following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Named parameter [B] is not registered with this procedure call
```

I have this entity class:

```
@Entity
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = NamedStoredProcedure.MyProc, procedureName = Procedures.MyProc, resultClasses = MyProcResult.class, parameters = {
        @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = ParameterName.A, type = String.class),
        @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = ParameterName.B, type = String.class)
})
public class CallProc{
.
.
}
```

I am sending required parameters:

```
StoredProcedureQuery publishedSessionStoredProcedure = entityManager.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery(NamedStoredProcedure.MyProc);
        publishedSessionStoredProcedure.setParameter(ParameterName.A, a);
        publishedSessionStoredProcedure.setParameter(ParameterName.B, b);
```

In procedure, also same no and type of parameters are expected.

What can be the reason ?

Answer (score 10):

I had the same exact issue, I chose to use 'createStoredProcedureQuery' instead of 'createNamedStoredProcedureQuery'

Try adding these lines:

```
.registerStoredProcedureParameter(ParameterName.A, String.class, ParameterMode.IN)
.registerStoredProcedureParameter(ParameterName.B, String.class, ParameterMode.IN)
```

Then your code should look something like this:

```
StoredProcedureQuery publishedSessionStoredProcedure = entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery(NamedStoredProcedure.MyProc, MyProcResult.class)    
       .registerStoredProcedureParameter(ParameterName.A, String.class, ParameterMode.IN)
       .registerStoredProcedureParameter(ParameterName.B, String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
    publishedSessionStoredProcedure.setParameter(ParameterName.A, a);
    publishedSessionStoredProcedure.setParameter(ParameterName.B, b);
```

For me registering the parameter did the trick hope it'll work for you 2

P.S. 
I also had to add SqlResultSetMapping for my object (in your case MyProcResult)

Comment: Yeah there are register methods for the parameter name or position. 

If you register the name, use the setParameter(String, ParameterType) method, and if you register the position use the setParameter(Integer, ParameterType) method.